# Add to array, redirect and display

Tags: plugins, redirect, array

I want add text to array and display after redirect and unset array.

```
class test{

    public function one(){

        $this->save(2, 'some');

        $url = get_site_url(null, '/redirect_to_two');
        wp_safe_redirect( $url );

    }

    public function two(){

        $this->display();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass some data over the redirect, you can do that by adding parameters to the redirect url with [`add_query_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/). But other more elegant solutions might exist also.

Single parameter,

```
wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'notice', 'success', get_site_url(null, '/redirect_to_two') ) );
exit;
```

or multiple parameters

```
wp_redirect( add_query_arg( array( 'notice' => 'success', 'foo' => 'bar' ), get_site_url(null, '/redirect_to_two') ) );
exit;
```

Then use `$_GET` to grab the parameter(s),

```
if ( ! empty( $_GET['notice'] ) && 'success' == $_GET['notice'] ) {
    // Do whatever.
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, I don't think you need to worry about unsetting arrays as data doesn't normally persist in WordPress. Once you do a redirect all the data in your `$variables` are gone.

Comment: Data in variables are gone but i still have in url something like mysite/login?notice=success and i not want this. If someone go back and return then is not good. I refresh site and still is.

Comment: What if you removed the query parameters with javascript from the url? Or would creative use of transients be applicable? E.g. after the save function create a one-use random string as a transient and add the same string as a query parameter to the redirect url. After redirect match the parameter and the transient to trigger a notice. Delete the transient afterwards.

Comment: Could perhaps use a cookie, then delete it after the redirect. But that wouldn't work if the browser had disabled them. There could still be an issue with returning to the site. Could perhaps put a quite short expiration time on the cookie.